# Sorting a std::vector with elements of type pair<int, string>, but in reverse order

Tags: c++

I am trying to sort a `std::vector` containing elements of type `pair <int, string>` in decreasing order.

I was trying to accomplish this by using `sort(Datas.begin(), Datas.end())`, but the end result is a `vector` sorted in ascending order. I also tried using `sort(Datas.begin(), Datas.end(), greater<int>)`, but this resulted in a compilation error.

For clarity, here is my code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, string>> Datas;
    Datas.emplace_back(4, "bbbbbbbbb");
    Datas.emplace_back(2, "yyytyuytuyt");
    Datas.emplace_back(20, "asdadxxsadas");
    Datas.emplace_back(1, "ccccccccc");

    sort(Datas.begin(), Datas.end());


    for (const auto& e : Datas)
        {
            cout << e.second << " " << e.first <<'\n';
        }
    cout << '\n';

}
```

Can somebody explain why the error occurs, and also explain how to sort a `std::vector` in decreasing order?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. 
When asking a question it is better to show what research you have done into your problem and post any code or errors if it applies.

Comment: Please clarify "best".  The word "best" is subjective.  Are you talking ease of typing?  performance? space savings?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following syntax:

`sort(Datas.rbegin(), Datas.rend());`

This syntax ensures that the list will be sorted in reverse order. You can also sort the list normally, then use `std::reverse`.

Your approach where you use `greater<int>` *would* successfully sort the list in reverse order if all the elements were of type `int`, but your code results in an error because you are passing elements of type `pair<int, string>` to `greater<int>`, which is not allowed.

Comment: Works. Thanks. I wish you all the best <3

Comment: @babidi If the answer answers your question, you should accept it, not just leave a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to Telescope's answer, if you want to use `std::greater`, you have to specify the correct type. In your case, it would be:

```
sort(Datas.begin(), Datas.end(), std::greater<std::pair<int,string>>());
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. I wish you all the best <3